# How to add Kafka Topic names with filter Regex to IBM MQ sink connector configs

Tags: regex, apache-kafka, ibm-mq, apache-kafka-connect

I have below config

```
 connectors: [
        {
          taskMax: 6,
          ......
          type: 'API',
          sourceTopic: 'A2_Source'
          destinationTopic: 'A3_Dest',
          isShadow: true,
        },
      ],
```

I want to add another topic with help of regex

```
 connectors: [
        {
          taskMax: 6,
          ......
          type: 'API',
          sourceTopicsRegex: ['A2_Source,(*_)_A4_Source']
          destinationTopic: 'A3_Dest',
          isShadow: true,
        },
  ],
```

The topic names expected are:

```
A2_Source
PRD_XX_YY_A4_Source
```

In the build it just shows `A2_Source,(*_)_A4_Source`

Could anyone confirm if it is the correct format or it is something else?

Answer (score 0):

The comma + outer square brackets are taken as a literal, not a list delimiter, and `(*` isn't a valid capture pattern.

To capture those topics your regex would be `(PRD_XX_YY_)?A(2|4)_Source`

Comment: So in case if I have different topic names for example, Int_WA and SRT_WS_PD_SPP_TPC with SRT _WS as something that can be replaced in future by anything else, then the regex would be (Int_WA|(SRT_WS)?_PD_SPP_TPC)

Comment: Or 'Int_WA|()?_PD_SPP_TPC'

Comment: Empty parenthesis won't do anything. You could use `\S+PD_SPP_TPC$` since "anything else" already captures SRT_WS. I suggest playing with some examples at https://regex101.com